# Why doesn't my mesh appear?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm creating an application with Delphi Seattle with FMX, and I'm working with creating meshes directly myself. What I don't understand is why this mesh doesn't appear:

```
Mesh.Data.VertexBuffer.Length := 4;
Mesh.Data.IndexBuffer.Length := 6;

with Mesh.Data.VertexBuffer do
begin
    Vertices[0] := TPoint3D.Create( 1,  1, 0);
    Vertices[1] := TPoint3D.Create( 1, -1, 0);
    Vertices[2] := TPoint3D.Create(-1, -1, 0);
    Vertices[3] := TPoint3D.Create(-1,  1, 0);

    TexCoord0[0] := TPointF.Create(0, 1);
    TexCoord0[1] := TPointF.Create(0, 1);
    TexCoord0[2] := TPointF.Create(0, 1);
    TexCoord0[3] := TPointF.Create(0, 1);
end;

with Mesh.Data.IndexBuffer do
begin
    Indices[0] := 0;
    Indices[1] := 1;
    Indices[2] := 2;

    Indices[3] := 2;
    Indices[4] := 3;
    Indices[5] := 0;
end;
```

The mesh has a colour material however when I run it, the mesh does not appear. Everything else does (a cube and a grid).

Comment: Code you wrote seems OK. Is camera pointing in right direction? What are material properties, does it have emission, what is ambient color of light source if you have one?

Comment: I checked the camera by adding a child object to the mesh, that showed up. I have a pale green colour material applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to set the mesh to TwoSide true, then I can see it. I did try rotating the object, but still couldn't see anything.